# OWIN Authorization fails if data is an object

Tags: .net, oauth, owin, access-token

How come this will work:

```
var data = "grant_type=password&client_id=" 
  + appSettings.authClientId 
  + "&username=" 
  + loginData.userName 
  + "&password=" 
  + loginData.password;

$http.post(
  appSettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "token", 
  data, 
  { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }
)
```

But this will generate a 400 error: clientId is null:

```
var data = {
    grant_type: "password",
    client_id: appSettings.authClientId,
    username: loginData.userName,
    password: loginData.password
};

$http.post(
  appSettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "token", 
  data, 
  { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }
)
```

Here's the code for the server side:

```
public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
{
    string clientId;
    string clientSecret;

    if (!context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
    {
        context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2) for OAuth 2.0 require you to send the parameters in the body:

HEADER:

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

BODY:

```
grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=A3ddj3w
```

and in fact your first request should work even if you change the **Content-Type** (header):

```
var data = "grant_type=password&client_id=" 
  + appSettings.authClientId 
  + "&username=" 
  + loginData.userName 
  + "&password=" 
  + loginData.password;

$http.post(
  appSettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "token", 
  data, 
  { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" } }
)
```

In your second sample code your request is in the body in this format:

{"grant_type":"password","username":"myusername","password":"mypassword"}

and your `ValidateClientAuthentication` cannot parse it.

You can try another approach using [transformRequest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: appSettings.apiServiceBaseUri + "token",
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authorizationBasic }, 
    data: { username: loginData.userName, password: loginData.password, grant_type: 'password' },
    transformRequest: function (obj) {
    var str = [];
    for (var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    return str.join("&");
    }
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    // deferred.resolve(data);
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    // deferred.reject("An error occured while fetching items");
});
```